# Replace text in status line flags

Tags: vim

How could I replace text in status line flags?

```
set laststatus=2
set statusline=
set statusline+=%r%m
```

Is there a way to replace `[RO]` to `Read only`, and `[+]` to `Modified`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional expressions when defining the statusline. Like:

```
set statusline+=%{&modified?\"Modified\":\"\"}
set statusline+=%{&readonly?\"Read\ Only\":\"\"}
```

See `:help 'statusline'` (it's a long text).